# Google Analytics Not Registering Transaction Quantity

Tags: magento, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics in Magento. Transactions, prices and everything else is being recorded, however the "Quantity" column is always 0 for every transaction. Annoyingly, the only time a quantity has shown up in the past month is the test I ran earlier today.
The code on our checkout success page is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ga("require", "ecommerce");

ga("ecommerce:addTransaction", {
    "id": "<?php echo $increment_id; ?>",                     // Transaction ID. Required.
    "affiliation": "REDACTED",   // Affiliation or store name.
    "revenue": "<?php echo $gtotal;?>",               // Grand Total.
    "shipping": "<?php echo $shippingVal;?>",                  // Shipping.
    "tax": "<?php echo $taxAmount;?>"                     // Tax.
});

<?php
$items = $order->getAllItems();
$itemcount=count($items);
$name=array();
$unitPrice=array();
$sku=array();
$ids=array();
$qty=array();
foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
{?>

ga("ecommerce:addItem", {
    "id": "<?php echo $increment_id; ?>",                     // Transaction ID. Required.
    "name": "<?php echo $item->getName(); ?>",    // Product name. Required.
    "sku": "<?php echo $item->getSku(); ?>",                 // SKU/code.
    "category": "",         // Category or variation.
    "price": "<?php echo $item->getPrice(); ?>",                 // Unit price.
    "quantity": "<?php echo $item->getQtyToInvoice(); ?>"                   // Quantity.
});
<?php
}
?>

ga("ecommerce:send");
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to install GA Debugger (for Chrome) to analyse the output in your dev console. It reveals valuable information useful for debugging. Also, try to use an integer for the quantity (although I don't think this should matter, but that's just how Google has specified it here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-transactions). Also, check that `$item->getQtyToInvoice();` is working correctly.

Comment: @nyuen, Thanks for that, I used the GA Debugger, but it's not flagged any problems. The debugger is getting and showing the correct data. I assume this means that there's a problem with the actual connection between Magento and GA? In that the collected data isn't being sent to GA.

Comment: Not really, if you see the data from GA debugger sending the data to GA then you should be seeing it in your reports. But then again I'm not familiar with Magento.